# spring - use beans from config.xml in SpringConfig.class

Tags: xml, spring, web-applications, import, spring-annotations

I have some context that changes from deployment to deployment, and some that is constant for all deployments.  The deployment-dependent bit is in an config.xml file that is external to the jar or war.  The static context stuff is in an annotation config class.  The trick is the annotation config uses beans from the config.xml.  For apps it is imported in the config class.  But for webapp it can't find that file.

SpringConfig class

```
@Component
@Configuration
@ImportResource("file:./config.xml")
public class SpringConfig {

   @Autowired private String local_timezone_string;
   @Autowired private String startDateFormatString;
   @Autowired private String startDateString;

   @Bean
   public TimeZone localTimeZone() {
      return TimeZone.getTimeZone(local_timezone_string);
   }

   @Bean
   public SimpleDateFormat startDateFormat() {
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(startDateFormatString);
      sdf.setTimeZone(localTimeZone());
      return sdf;
   }

   @Bean
   public long jaceThreadStartDate() throws ParseException {
      return startDateFormat().parse(jaceThreadStartDateString).getTime();
   }

   ... a bunch of other beans
}
```

and config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

   <bean id="local_timezone_string" class="java.lang.String"><constructor-arg value="Canada/Atlantic"/></bean>
   <bean id="startDateFormatString" class="java.lang.String"><constructor-arg value="yyyy-MM-dd"/></bean>
   <bean id="startDateString" class="java.lang.String"><constructor-arg value="2017-04-06"/></bean>

   ... other beans

</beans>
```

config.xml is not included in the jar so that the SpringConfig looks for config.xml in the deployment folder and uses deployment specific context.  But when deploying SpringConfig in webapp via WebApplicationInitializer - it can no longer find config.xml.  Of course.  So, how can the beans in the deployment-dependent context be loaded into the static context in a webapp?  Is there a way to tell an AnnotationConfigApplicationContext to scan a package for @Configuration and @Components *after* registering beans from an xml config in a webapp?

I'm thinking maybe a class derived from AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext that - in the constructor - calls setParent(config.xml context) and then calls the AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class).

Or even: instead of calling AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(String... basePackages), instead call AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(), then setParent(...), then scan(...).

Answer (score 0):

So there's a way using setParent() and scan().

```
@Component
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SpringConfig.class);
    @Autowired private DriverManagerDataSource pgDataSource;
    @Autowired private String local_timezone_string;
    @Autowired private String startDateFormatString;
    @Autowired private String startDateString;

    private static ApplicationContext getVariableContext() throws Exception {

        ApplicationContext variableContext = null;
        try {
            variableContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("./config.xml");
            log.info("got config.xml from file system");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                variableContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");
                log.info("got config.xml from class path");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.info("failed to get config.xml");
                throw new Exception(...);
            }
        }
        return variableContext;
    }

    public static WebApplicationContext getWebApplicationContext() throws ServletException {

        try {
            ApplicationContext variableContext = getVariableContext();
            AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
            appContext.setParent(variableContext);
            appContext.scan(
                    "com.us.systemdiagnostics",
                    "com.us.systemdiagnostics.webservice"
            );
            appContext.refresh();
            return appContext;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServletException(...);
        }
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getStandAloneApplicationContext() throws ServletException {

        try {
            ApplicationContext variableContext = getVariableContext();
            AnnotationConfigApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
            appContext.setParent(variableContext);
            appContext.scan(
                    "com.us.systemdiagnostics",
                    "com.us.systemdiagnostics.webservice"
            );
            appContext.refresh();
            return appContext;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(...);
        }
    }

    ... beans, etc ...
}
```